# Initializing Object With Non-Existent Value

Tags: java, list, constructor

Is it possible to initialize a constructor if one of the value from parameter is non existent?

```
public Plane(List<String> e) {

        this.type = e.get(0);
        this.name = e.get(1);
        this.color = e.get(2);
    }
```

On the third line of the below list, the value for name is missing.

```
type,name,color
commercial,boeing,white
commercial,airbus,white
commercial,white
```

So if e.get(1) for line 4 doesn't exist, I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

is there a way to create the object without lifting the exception?

Comment: Normally, you would use telescoping constructors to handle this kind of thing, but the fact that you're passing a List is a problem. Is it your idea to pass a list, or is this part of the assignment/problem you're dealing with?

Comment: I'm working from a file structured like the example, which I transformed into a list, so that each comma inside the file/list corresponds to type,name,color respectively. So my goal is to create an object for each line of the file

Comment: How can you know which of the values is missing? In your example data is the name 'white', or is the name missing?

Comment: Its supposed to have the same structure type,name,color if one of those is missing, like in the example : commercial,white (the name is missing). e.get() will not receive a value and the object will not be instantiated

Comment: your file is poorly structured: a comma separator must be present even when data is empty `commercial,,white`

Comment: You are right but what about when the last data is missing `commercial,,` e.get(2) doesn't correspond to anything

Comment: `if ( e.size() < 3 ) { /* color is empty*/ }`
or use some of java csv libraries

Comment: I added a try catch block to deal with the exception lifted by `commercial,,` and create multiple validation methods to verify if each attribute (type,name) is empty ` ,boeing,white`

Comment: You can't get what you want with a list. Since you're the one packaging data into a list, you're also the one who can solve the problem, but first, you have to let go of your preconceived notions of the solution.

Answer (score -1):

you can intialize like this

this.color = e.length>=3?e.get(2):"";

Comment: `List` does not have `length` attribute !